# Fill in Cayley table for a commutative ring with unity

Tags: discrete-mathematics, cayley-table

[image]

Let M={0,1,a,b} be a commutative ring with unity. I'm supposedt to fill in the Cayley tables. Can someone help me with the table for the multiply table.
I think that $a*b=b*a=a$ do to commutative ring.
Is the multiplicative identity $1$?
Is $0*1=0$ for example?

I think that the Cayley table for + is:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The elements of a commutative ring under addition must be an abelian group. Since there are four elements, that group in this case must be $\mathbb Z_4$ or $\mathbb Z_2^2$. Since there is a non-zero element ($1$) for which $1+1\ne0$, the abelian group must be $\mathbb Z_4$ and the ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ with the associations $a=2$ and $b=3$. Filling out the tables should now be easy.

Comment: $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z[X]/(X^2)$ is another example, in characteristic $2$.

Comment: I have not learned what Z/4Z means? Can you explain more

Comment: The integers modulo $4$ – two integers are the same modulo $4$ if they have the same remainder when divided by $4$.

Comment: Is Z/4Z the same as Z4?

Comment: @Erika no; the first is referring to a ring, the second to a group.

Comment: Is (M, *) isomorphic to (Z4, *) and if so why?

Comment: @Erika Please ask another question.

Comment: I thought that (M,+) was isomophic to (Z4,+).  Then is (M, *) isomorhpic to (Z4, *)?